# Dell Latitude 3190 BIOS doesn't list hard drive

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, bios

Had Ubuntu on it and I got rid of it.  Now the BIOS doesn't list the hard drive even though I installed Windows 10 by USB drive.

I can search the drive from the BIOS, but I can't find the path for the laptop to boot up to the new OS. Windows 10 Pro, is the OS on it now. Any suggestions?

As for partitions, I deleted them when I wiped the drive, and let windows assign its own. Not certain what CSM is, and I am sure which partition type it is.

Comment: MBR or GPT partition?  Is CSM enabled or disabled? [Edit] your question instead of submitting a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Start from (Boot from) the Windows bootable ISO to:

1. Delete ALL partitions, and then,
2. Install Windows 10 normally and let it assign its normal 3 partitions.

Comment: YES, that worked, THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: Perhaps you can accept my answer since my suggestion worked. There is an accept button in the question.